# Can't get jQuery validate to validate a checkbox field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting jQuery validate to ensure that a checkbox field has been checked. Other fields validate fine.

Here's my JS:

```
$(".my-form").validate({
  errorLabelContainer: ".form-errors",
  wrapper: "li",
  rules: {
    cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond: "You must accept our terms and conditions"
  },
});
```

And the HTML for the checkbox field (which I have no control of, as it's auto-generated with a CMS tag):

```
<div>
  <label for="cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond">Accept Terms &amp; Conditions</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond" value="n" />
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond[]" value="Yes"  />&nbsp;Accept Terms & Conditions</label> <div style="clear:left"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this? I copied the rule/message from the [demo on the jQuery validate page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/).

Comment: `$('.myform')` searches for elements with the class 'my-form'... are you sure you didn't mean to search by id? (#)

Comment: .my-form is definitely correct. I have text fields validating perfectly in the same form but I stripped them from my example to keep this question simple.

Comment: whats with the brackets of cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond checkbox?

Comment: The brackets are just something that my CMS spits out when outputting this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond[]" value="Yes"  />
```

should include id element and should be

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond" name="cf_enquiry_accept_terms_cond[]" value="Yes"  />
```

Comment: Why? O.o Also if you kept with this schema, you would end up with duplicate ids which is a big no-no...

Comment: The rules are applied on ids not on name of inputs

Comment: I can't enter an ID as this field is auto-generated by a CMS tag. All fields have these name fields though.

Comment: Okay, I'm marking this question as answered I'm going to build these fields manually as per the above format, instead of trying to get it working with the way it's currently spitting them out from the CMS tag.